# Need understanding this multivariable calculus question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm currently trying to solve the following question.

> Below is a function $f$. We are interested in how changes in the values of the input variables $x, y$ or parameters $a, b, c$ affect $f$. To that aim, we write $f$ as a function of both its input variables and its parameters, using the notation $f (x, y; a, b, c)$. The “gradient of $f$ towards **v**”, denoted as $\nabla$**v**$f$, is the vector of all partial derivatives of $f$ to the variables/parameters listed in **v**. Fill in the blanks.
>
> - $f(x,y;a,b,c)=a \exp(2x)+by^2+cxy$
> - $\nabla_{x,y}f(x,y;a,b,c)=$
> - $\nabla_{a,b,c}f(x,y;a,b,c)=$
> - If $\delta, \epsilon$ are very small real numbers, what is $f(1,2;3,4 +\delta,5 + \epsilon)-f(1,2; 3,4,5)$ approximately? Explain how you obtained the answer.

What I've understood is that we have to first calculate the gradients for $f$ with regards to $x, y$ first and then with regards $a, b, c$. The gradients that I've calculated are:

$$
\nabla_{x,y} f(x,y;a,b,c) = 
\left
[\begin{array}{c}
2 a\exp(2x)+cy \\
2by+cx \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
\nabla_{a,b,c} f(x,y;a,b,c) = 
\left
[\begin{array}{c}
\exp(2x) \\
y^2 \\
xy \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

For the last part I solved it by just substituting the values and got the follow answer:

$$
f(1,2;3,4+\delta,5+\epsilon) - f(1,2;3,4,5)\\
=[3\exp(2)+4\delta+2\epsilon+26] - [3\exp(2)+26]\\
=4\delta+2\epsilon\\
$$

I might be completely missing the whole point of this question, but this is what I was able to understand. Is this the correction solution? I'd appreciate any help in understanding this question.

Comment: Your gradients are good. Your calculation with $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ is also correct, although not really the way that they probably meant you to do it. They probably meant you to use $\nabla_{a,b,c}f(1,2;3,4,5)\cdot\langle0,\delta,\epsilon\rangle$ instead. If $f$ weren't linear in $a$, $b$, and $c$, then this would come out differently (and more simply).

Comment: @TobyBartels Could you please explain how I would go about solving for   and  with ∇,,(1,2;3,4,5)⋅⟨0,,⟩?

Comment: I don't understand under what conditions you're trying to solve for them.  In the question as you quoted it, you aren't asked to find them or given enough information to find them.  You got the answer: $4\delta+2\epsilon$, only you got it in a different way from how they probably intended.

Comment: Note that according to your previous answer, $\nabla_{a,b,c}f(x,y;a,b,c)=\langle\exp(2x),y^2,xy\rangle$, so $\nabla_{a,b,c}f(1,2;3,4,5)=\langle\exp2,4,2\rangle$. Then $\nabla_{a,b,c}f(1,2;3,4,5)\cdot\langle0,\delta,\epsilon\rangle=(\exp2)(0)+(4)(\delta)+(2)(\epsilon)=4\delta+2\epsilon$, which is the same thing that you got for $f(1,2;3+0,4+\delta,5+\epsilon)-f(1,2;3,4,5)$. In general, the method with the gradient (which is usually easier) only gives an approximation to the actual difference, but it's exactly the same in this case because $f$ is linear in $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: By the way, I'm writing vectors with angle brackets and commas, but instead of $\langle0,\delta,\epsilon\rangle$, you might prefer to write $\left[\matrix{0\cr\delta\cr\epsilon}\right]$ or even $\left[\matrix{0&\delta&\epsilon}\right]$. Then again, if you're going to write vectors as matrices, it's best to make the gradients row vectors, so $\left[\matrix{\exp(2x)&y^2&xy}\right]$ instead of $\left[\matrix{\exp(2x)\cr y^2\cr xy}\right]$. But write them however you like.